# How to create custom section layout options for SharePoint online modern site pages?

Tags: layout, sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp-js, sharepointframework

SharePoint provides default layout options below as mentioned in the screenshot. How can we create custom section layout options as per our needs? If there are any ways to create custom section layout options then please let me know your thoughts on the same.

[image]

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom section layout options for SharePoint Online modern site pages involves using SharePoint Framework (SPFx) extensions. SPFx extensions allow you to extend the functionality of SharePoint and customize modern pages. In this case, you'll need creating an application customizer extension to add custom section layout options.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, No.

Currently there is no SharePoint out of the box or custom code way available to create custom section layout options for SharePoint online modern site pages.

**Additional**:

- You can only create page template to reuse the existing site pages
- You cannot add new "custom section layout options" (as shown in image) using SharePoint framework (SPFx)
- You can only use the single part app pages in SharePoint Online using SharePoint framework (SPFx). Check: [Using single part app pages in SharePoint Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/single-part-app-pages?)